# How to add some HTML widget art in Microsoft words?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003

I'm a system analyst. I need to write a document in Microsoft Word, I looking for "clip art' or 'auto sharp' for HTML widget/art like check box, form, text-field...etc    so that I can use in my documents. where can I find those add on?

Comment: Is your question "How do I put (something similar to) html elements into a word document?"

Comment: yes how to put html elements (art) into microsoft word 2003. so that i can write technical documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Options/Customized Ribbon* make sure you have the **Developer** box checked (on the right hand side). Once the developer menu is enabled you will have a multitude on HTML-like tags/widgets available.

Comment: where is this "option" under microsoft word 2003 ? i cannot see from top toolbar

Comment: In 2003: Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then Word Options.
Click Popular, and then select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box.

Comment: sorry, i cant find that. on top toolbar. i got 'file,edit,view,insert,format,tools,table,window,help"

Comment: @user9179 - I think the developer toolbar is only in 2007 and later version of office, but in 2003 you have other options. Click on View | Toolbars and under Forms you have the checkbox, Text Form....